# How to enable FTP access to a server behind an Cisco Pix 515?

Tags: ftp, cisco-pix

I have a Windows 2003 web server sitting behind a Cisco Pix 515 firewall. HTTP access is fine, but I can't make FTP access to work.

The configuration I'm trying:

```
fixup protocol ftp 20
static (inside,outside) <external-IP> <internal-IP> netmask 255.255.255.255 0 0
conduit permit tcp host <external-IP> eq www any
conduit permit tcp host <external-IP> eq ftp-data any
conduit permit tcp host <external-IP> eq ftp any
```

I also tried "fixup protocol ftp 21" and "no fixup protocol 20"; as they didn't work, I removed them.

It connects successfully, I type my username and password just fine. When I try any command I get:

```
C:\>ftp <server-name>
Connected to <server-name>.
220 Microsoft FTP Service
User (<server-name>:(none)): <username>
331 Password required for <username>.
Password:
230 User <username> logged in.
ftp> dir
500 Invalid PORT Command.
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for /bin/ls.
```

And it sits there forever. I can see on eventvwr that the server drops the connection after the time-out I configured is reached.

If I try from Internet Explorer I get a message box:

```
200 Type set to A
500 Invalid PORT command
500 'LPRT 6,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,4,0,0,0,0,34,113,2,6,71': command not understood
```

FTP to this server from inside my LAN works fine.

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What version of PIX firmware are you running 6,7 or 8?

Comment: I'm using PIX Version 5.1(4)

Comment: It would be a nice idea to upgrade it !

Comment: Do your pix logs show anything? fixup protocol ftp 21 should be all you need

Comment: Adam, I'm no PIX specialist, I don't even know how to check its logs.

Answer (score 1):

Remove:

```
fixup protocol ftp 20
```

and just add:

```
fixup protocol ftp
```

without a port number.  A port number is not needed.  In addition to this, you may need to issue a clear xlate for it to take effect right away...however, this will disconnect any/all active connections (and can cause other issues).

**Edited to add:**

As Zephyr asked in comments above, it is important to know what version of PIX software you're running as Cisco replaced fixup with inspect.

Comment: He said : "I also tried "fixup protocol ftp 21" and "no fixup protocol 20"; as they didn't work, I removed them.".
I made the same answer before reding the question a second time ;)

Comment: But I also suspect that he did this and tried them right away before trying clear xlate.

Comment: When I try "fixup protocol ftp" it returns an error message: "usage: [no] fixup protocol <prot> <port>[-<port>]"

Comment: I googled clear xlate and I don't think it is necessary because the command "static (inside,outside) <external-IP> <internal-IP> netmask 255.255.255.255 0 0" was already in place

Comment: What does a "show fixup" return?

Comment: GregD, it returns:
   fixup protocol http 80
   fixup protocol h323 1720
   fixup protocol rsh 514
   fixup protocol sqlnet 1521
   no fixup protocol smtp 25
   fixup protocol ftp 20

Comment: Try these commands in this order: no fixup protocol ftp 20 | fixup protocol ftp 21

Comment: Also, is your FTP site setup to accept all incoming IP addresses or specific ones (like your internal ones)?

Comment: GregD, now "show fixup" shows: fixup protocol http 80
fixup protocol h323 1720 | fixup protocol rsh 514 | fixup protocol sqlnet 1521 | no fixup protocol smtp 25 | fixup protocol ftp 21 | but it's still not working. Thanks anyway!

Comment: GregD, my FTP site allows any IP address to connect to it; I can connect, but I can't even see its contents (dir) or upload/download any file (put/get). IIS shows I'm connected.

Comment: What FTP client are you using?  Have you tried active vs. passive ftp on your client outside of the firewall?

Comment: I tried using both ftp.exe and Internet Explorer to access the ftp site.

Comment: GregD, I tried using FileZilla and it's working. How strange.